Spring Batch dynamic step dependencies
I have spring-boot web application. With endpoint POST /persons/bulk which accepts as body list of
Person which should save to database. Input list can have 10000+ items (this is hard condition, change as using kafka is not possible now), and I need to store each person to postgres db.
Person has dependency to itself through childPersonIds field.
Incoming request can look like this
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "childPersonIds": [3]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kate",
        "childPersonIds": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jake",
        "childPersonIds": []
    }
]

When using spring-batch it is tempting for me, to do:

in runtime create step per each wave in which should be incoming entities processed (because of db integrity constraints)

step 0: Kate, Jake
step 1: John
step 2: other potential parents, e.g. if John has also parent
It is expected to have max 5 layers based on incoming data


do not defined step or even job as Bean

Implementation could look like this:
@Service
public class PersonProcessingService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonProcessingService.class);

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public PersonProcessingService(final JobRepository jobRepository, final JobLauncher jobLauncher, final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    void importPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        SimpleJobBuilder jobBuilder = new JobBuilder("importPersonsJob", jobRepository)
                .start(someInitialStep());

        List<List<Person>> layeredData = prepareLayeredData(persons);

        int i = 0;
        for (List<Person> layer : layeredData) {
            final Iterator<Person> layerIterator = layer.iterator();
            Step personStep = new StepBuilder("importPersonLayerStep[%d]".formatted(i++), jobRepository)
                    .<Person, Person>chunk(1, transactionManager)
                    .reader(() -> layerIterator.hasNext() ? layerIterator.next() : null)
                    .writer(new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>())
                    .build();
            jobBuilder.next(personStep);
        }

        try {
            final JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(jobBuilder.build(), new JobParameters());
            logger.info("Job completed: {}", jobExecution.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private List<List<Person>> prepareLayeredData(List<Person> persons) {
        // in first layer will be persons without children
        // in second layer will be persons with children only in first layer
        // etc.
        throw new IllegalStateException("not implemented yet");
    }

    private Step someInitialStep() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("not implemented yet");
    }

    record Person(int id, String name, List<Integer> childPersonIds) {}
}

Questions are:

Is this valid solution which will can potentially benefit from all spring batch advantages such as distributed processing etc.
If this is not valid solution, how should I solve this problem?

I want to have only one application context, as I see similar advice somewhere else.
